# Show Vector Items C++

Tags: c++, class, vector

I ask something about vectors."purchaseItem", which is the variable that I define as a vector, I add the ProductName variable of the object selected from the product class.Then I display the elements in this variable with a for loop. So far, no problem. What I want is to show the "pcs" value entered from the keyboard next to the vector elements. I want each added vector element to have its own "pcs" value, next to the element. How can I do that? I would be glad if you help.

```
void PurchaseProduct() {
int search, found, productPcs, a, randomNumber;
int pcs;
double totalBill = 0.0;

cout << "Lütfen Satın Almayı Düşünüdüğünüz Ürün Tür Adetini Giriniz: ";
cin >> a;
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    cout << "Lütfen Satın Almak İstediğiniz Ürün ID Numarasını Girin: ";
    cin >> search;
    found = Search(search);
    if (found == -1) {
        cout << "Ürün Bulunamadı!!!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ürün Bulundu." << endl;
        cout << "Ürün ID: " << product[found].getProductID() << "\n Ürün İsmi: " << product[found].getProductName() << "\n Ürün Adedi: " << product[found].getUpdateProductPcs() << "\n Ürün Fiyatı: " << product[found].getProductSalePrice() << " TL\n" << endl;
        product[found].setProductPcs(product[found].getUpdateProductPcs());
        sa[found].setProductBuyPrice(product[found].getProductSalePrice());
        randomNumber = rand() % 100000 + 1;
        sa[found].setSaleID(randomNumber);
        orderID = sa[found].getSaleID();
        sa[found].setSaleOrder(product[found].getProductName());
        cout << "Satın Almak İstediğiniz Adedi Girin: ";
        cin >> pcs;
        while (pcs > product[found].getUpdateProductPcs()) {
            cout << "\nGirilen Adette Ürün Mevcut Değil.\nŞuan Stokta, " << product[found].getUpdateProductPcs() << " Adet Ürün Bulunmaktadır. Lütfen Tekrar Satın Almak İstediğiniz Adedi Girin: " << endl;
            cin >> pcs;
        }
        sa[found].setSalePcs(pcs);
        sa[found].setSaleBill(pcs);
        totalBill += sa[found].getSaleBill();
        productPcs = product[found].getProductPcs() - pcs;
        product[found].setProductPcs(productPcs);
        cout << "Ürün Sepete Eklendi.\n" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < sa[found].getSaleOrder().size(); i++) {
            purchaseItem.push_back(sa[found].getSaleOrder()[i]);
        }
        /*for (int j = 0; j < sa[found].getSalePcs().size(); j++) {
            purchasePcs.push_back(sa[found].getSalePcs()[i]);
        }*/
    
    }
}
cout << "Toplam Sepet Tutarı: " << totalBill << "\n" << endl;




ShowProduct();}

void Orders() {
int menu;
cout << "Sipariş Numarası= " << orderID << "\n" << endl;
cout << "Sepetteki Ürünler:\n";
for (int j = 0; j < purchaseItem.size(); j++) {
    cout << "\t\t" << purchaseItem[j] << endl;
}
/*for (int k = 0; k < purchasePcs.size(); k++) {
    cout << "\t\t" << purchasePcs[k] << endl;
}*/
cout << "Satış Menüsü için 1\t\t" << "Ana Menü için 0" << endl;
cin >> menu;
if (menu == 0) {
    MainMenu();
}
else if (menu == 1) {
    PurchaseMenu();
}
else {
    cout << "Tanımlanmayan Giriş!!!" << endl;
    Orders();
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the declaration of the purchaseItem vector ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't provide the declaration of the vector `purchaseItem`.

Assuming that all your functions are part of one class, which has `purchaseItem` as a member, you can solve your problem by changing the type of elements in the `purchaseItem` vector. If one element has several members, you can declare a struct for it :

```
struct purchaseItem_elem {
    // Here : declaration of all members that you want in one element of your vector
    // for example :
    int pcs;
    string name;
};
```

And change the declaration of your purchaseItem vector accordingly :

```
vector<purchaseItem_elem> purchaseItem;
```